# UIwebview not changing frame

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

im trying to make it so that the when the keyboard appears, the size of the UIWebView also changes so it can be displayed on screen.

the code seems to work for the toolbar but not for the webview.

here is my code:

```
- (void) repositionControllers
{
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect toolbarFrame = toolbar.frame;
    CGRect WebviewFrame =  Webview.frame;

    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;


    toolbarFrame.origin.y = screenHeight - 216 - toolbarFrame.size.height;
    toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;

    WebviewFrame.size.height = screenHeight - 216 - toolbarFrame.size.height;
    Webview.frame = WebviewFrame;

}
```

can anyone see what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the web view's origin.y 0? If not, that's your problem; you can't just adjust the height in accordance with the screen height, but rather you must take the web view's origin into account.

Comment: i have tried     self.WebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, (int)(toolbarY+toolbarHeight), [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",320] floatValue], newHeight);
i know its a very clumsy way but i did it do the the correct values are CGFloat. but it still does seem to work.